# copy string to char**

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

I do not understand why the following code:

```
char** receive_message(char** ret)
{
    char* temp = "text";

    strcpy(&ret, temp);
    return ret;
}
```

gives this error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     strcpy(&ret, temp);
```

I'm trying to copy a message that is generated inside a function to a char* array that is allocated outside the function.

Comment: Why do you pass and return a `char**`?

Comment: You're confusing `&ret` and `*ret`. But why is ret `char**`, and why do you return it?

Comment: I need a function that gets me a message with msgget as a string.

Comment: There is not even a call to `getmsg`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: And note that `char *? is a _pointer to char_, not an array.

Comment: That was my minimal example, my getmsg works as intended, I just don't understand pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
strcpy(*ret, temp);
```

Instead of

```
strcpy(&ret, temp);
```

You need to deference char ** instead of taking a reference of it.

Answer (score 1):

It wants something of type char* whereas &ret is of type char***.

You could maybe pass it *ret which is of type char*.

Answer (score 0):

`ret` is a `char**` but `strcpy` expects a `char*`

You then take the address of `&ret` making it `char***`

Either pass `ret` as `char*` into `receive_message` or dereference it when passing it to `strcpy (*ret, temp)`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `strcpy` the address of a pointer to a pointer to `char`... That's 2 levels of indirection too many.  You do not need all these indirections, you can simplify `receive_message` this way:

```
char *receive_message(char *ret) {
    return strcpy(ret, "text");
}
```

Not really worth a separate function ;-)

It is useful to pass the address of the pointer to `receive_function` is you intend for this function to modify the pointer in the calling scope, as would be required if you need to reallocate the buffer, but since you do not pass the size, such reallocation would be hazardous.